# Writing Dataframe having Cyrillic character to HDFS is changing the encoding

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, utf-8, cyrillic

I have to read 1 XML file from HDFS having Cyrillic characters and parse that file using spark (scala), perform some transformation and write it back to HDFS. When I am writting the file I am not able to see the original Cyrillic character, those are being replaced by ???. I suspect the reason being after writting it to HDFS the charset is getting converted to  charset=us-ascii.
I am using spark 1.6 and scala 2.10

I tried to set the default encoding of the program using multiple approaches:-

```
1) System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8")  
2) sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")  
  .option("rowTag", "resourceListing")  
  .option("charset","UTF8")  
  .option("encoding","UTF8")  
  .load(input_path)  
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")  
  .option("delimiter",  "\t")  
  .option("encoding", "UTF8")  
  .option("charset","UTF8")  
  .mode("overwrite")  
  .save("output_path")  
3) from maven -    
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>  
4) from spark-submit -  
 --driver-java-options -Dfile.encoding=utf-8  
 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```

Input file looks like :-

```
<resourceListing>
  <resource language="de" title="Mailand"></resource>
  <resource language="en" title="Milan"></resource>
  <resource language="pt" title="Milão" ></resource>
  <resource language="mi" title="米兰"></resource>
  <resource language="de" title="Köln"></resource>
 </resourceListing>
```

Actual Output :-

```
WrappedArray([null,de,Mailand], [null,en,Milan], [null,pt,Mil??o], 
[null,mi,??????], [null,de,K?ln])
```

Expected output :-

```
WrappedArray([null,de,Mailand], [null,en,Milan], [null,pt,Milão], 
[null,mi,米兰], [null,de,Köln])
```

Comment: Just to be sure..  your expected output is from the spark-shell console?  I say that because 'WrappedArray' is not something that is normally written/outputted to a csv file.  Is the csv file correct ?

Comment: Wrapped array is just an example where I just read the XML file and wrote it as Text in HDFS with sqlContext.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv".option("delimiter",  "\t").option("encoding", "UTF8").option("charset","UTF8") .mode("overwrite") .save("output_path")  . Originally I will transform it and write the file in tabular format as Parquet/Text